# Satzstruktur von "je, desto" in Schweizerdeutsch und Hochdeutsch

Tags: grammaticality

Ich habe die folgende Sätze auf Schweizerdeutsch und Hochdeutsch gesehen:

1. Je lauter der Lehrer spricht, desto besser hören ihn die Schüler

Grammatik: je (mit Adj) + Subject + Objekt + Verb, **desto (mit Adj) + Verb + Personalpronomen + Subject.**

2. Je besser sie ihn kennt, desto netter findet sie ihn.

Grammatik:
je (mit Adj) + Subject + Objekt + Verb, **desto (mit Adj) + Verb + Subject + Personalpronomen.**

Welche Version von oben ist grammatisch richtig?

Comment: kleine Anmerkung: ich denke 'ihn' ist in beiden Fällen ein Personalpronomen, kein Reflexivpronomen. Davon abgesehen kommen mir beide Sätze richtig vor..

Comment: @ye-ti-800 Danke! ich habe die Frage angepasst.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Der Hauptsatz *Desto besser hören ihn die Schüler.* könnte auch allein stehen. Im ersten Beispiel sind beide Reihenfolgen daher zumindest akzeptabel:

> Je lauter der Lehrer spricht, desto besser hören die Schüler ihn. *(gut!)*
>
> Je lauter der Lehrer spricht, desto besser hören ihn die Schüler. *(akzeptabel)*

---

Stehen mehrere Personalpronomen hintereinander, muss die Reihenfolge Nominativ-Akkusativ-Dativ-Genitiv sein, allerdings gilt das wirklich nur für reine Pronomenreihungen. Kommt ein Nomen vor, so werden zuerst alle Pronomen aufgereiht, dann die Nomen:

> Erst will sie `(Nom)` ihm `(Dat)` ihren Wagen `(Akk)` nicht überlassen, doch nach einer Weile gibt sie `(Nom)` ihn `(Akk)` ihm `(Dat)`.
>
> Sie kann sich `(Dat)` seiner `(Gen)` sicher sein.

So erklärt sich auch das zweite Beispiel:

> Je besser sie ihn kennt, desto netter findet sie ihn. *(gut!)*
>
> <s>Je besser sie ihn kennt, desto netter findet ihn sie.</s> *(Mist!)*

(Allerdings ist die falsche Fallreihung bei Personalpronomen wohl einer der häufigsten Grammatikfehler, den Muttersprachler machen.)

Comment: Ich verstehe nicht, warum du den ersten Satz nur akzeptabel findest.

Comment: Du meinst sicher den zweiten Satz in meinem ersten Beispiel: Setze *den Lehrer* für *ihn* ein, dann wirkt der Satz sofort holperig. Wenn du stattdessen *sie* für *die Schüler* einsetzt, ist die Kasusreihung der Pronomen falsch. Und niemand sagt: *hören den Lehrer sie*, stattdessen sagt man *hören sie den Lehrer*. Man steht damit also auf dünnem Eis.

Comment: Ja, den Satz meinte ich, den ersten aus der Frage, hätte ich deutlicher schreiben sollen. Dass man das nicht sagen würde, wenn statt des Personalpronomens ein Substantiv mit Artikel stünde, sehe ich nicht als Argument dafür, dass der Satz unschön ist. Ich hätte gedacht, dass Teil der Antwort gerade ist, dass ich Personalpronomen anders verhalten.

Comment: Deshalb schrieb ich ja auch *akzeptabel* und nicht etwa *schlecht*.

Comment: Ok, ich finde Deine Antwort auch akzeptabel ;)

Answer (score 1):

Ich verstehe nicht, warum denn niemand aufs **Schweizerdeutsche** eingeht, obwohl es doch explizit genannt worden ist. Dort kann es sich nämlich anders verhalten.

Der Grund für den Unterschied liegt darin, dass es im Schweizerdeutschen – ähnlich wie z.B. im Italienischen – zwei Reihen von Personalpronomen gibt, nämlich die gewöhnlichen, unbetonten und die zur Hervorhebung verwendeten betonten. Dabei zeichnen sich die unbetonten Pronomen dadurch aus, dass sie sich in der Aussprache an das vorangehende Verb bzw. in Nebensätzen an die Konjunktion anhängen, gewissermassen wie eine Endung. Sie stehen somit ausserhalb der gewöhnlichen Reihenfolge der Satzglieder.

Ich erlaube mir übrigens eine Vereinfachung des Beispielsatzes. Zur Illustration des Phänomens genügt es nämlich, wenn das Vorfeld durch eine beliebige Adverbiale besetzt ist, sei es nun die komplexe Je-desto-Konstruktion (schweizerdeutsch eher wi-wi) oder ein schlichtes «so».

Die gewöhnliche Reihenfolge bei durch Adverbiale besetztem Vorfeld ist *(Adverbiale –) Verb – Subjekt – Objekt:*

1. So verstö d Schüeler der Lehrer besser.

Das unbetonte Pronomen folgt jedoch auf das Verb:

2. So verstö’ne d Schüeler besser.

Das betonte hingegen steht eher an seiner gewöhnlichen Stelle:

3. So verstö d Schüeler *ihn* besser.

Bei mehreren unbetonten Pronomen gilt ebenfalls die gewöhnliche Reihenfolge:

4. So verstö si’ne besser.

Im **Hochdeutschen** gibt es nur eine einzige Reihe von Pronomen. Das mag der Grund sein, warum für Janka die gewöhnliche Reihenfolge bevorzugt. Aber selbstverständlich können die hochdeutschen Pronomen betont sein oder nicht, auch wenn sie immer die gleiche Form haben. Und in diesem Fall ist auch im Hochdeutschen die Umkehrung der Reihenfolge möglich, mag sie auch weniger üblich sein als im Schweizerdeutschen.

Dabei ist ebenfalls die Betontheit wichtig. Dies lässt sich daran erkennen, dass bei denjenigen Pronomen, die normalerweise unbetont sind, – etwa bei den Reflexivpronomen – auch im Hochdeutschen die Umkehrung den Normalfall darstellt, vgl. z.B.:

5. So wäscht sich der Lehrer die Hände.

Im Vergleich dazu ist die gewöhnliche Reihenfolge zwar auch möglich, aber weniger üblich (oder?):

6. So wäscht der Lehrer sich die Hände.

Comment: *»Ich verstehe nicht, warum denn niemand aufs Schweizerdeutsche eingeht«* - Ich verstehe das schon: Auf german.stackexchange sind leider nicht sonderlich viele Schweizer unterwegs.

Comment: Die Frage drehte sich um *je ... desto*. Inwiefern spielt da die Einleitung mit *so* eine Rolle? (Vor allem im Fall der hochdeutschen Sätze)

Comment: @Hubert Schölnast: Sowohl Janka als auch ich haben die Frage so verstanden, dass es eigentlich um die unterschiedliche Reihenfolge der Satzglieder geht. Diese unterschiedliche Reihenfolge lässt sich in jedem Satz beobachten, wo das Vorfeld durch eine Adverbiale besetzt ist. Das mit «desto» eingeleitete Satzglied ist ein äusserst komplexes Beispiel für eine solche Adverbiale – derart komplex, dass es meines Erachtens vom eigentlichen Problem der Satzgliedreihenfolge nur ablenkt. Darum habe ich ein einfacheres Beispiel für eine solche Adverbiale gewählt, nämlich das Satzglied «so».

Comment: Ok, danke für die Erklärung